# What is the fate of the Hellburner crew?

Tags: alliance-union

Is there any indication in Cherryh’s later books in the Alliance-Union universe where the crew of the Hellburner ended up? *Hellburner* takes place in 2324 C.E. and *Downbelow Station* almost 30 years later so there’s no guarantee they’ve even survived—but do we ever actually know for certain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [C. J. Cherryh’s site](http://www.cherryh.com/WaveWithoutAShore/?page_id=820&cpage=13#comment-24673), Jcrow9 posted:

> In personal correspondence CJ told me that Dekker’s crew is also aboard Norway. ISTR she said that Norway’s riders are the only ones left with all-original crews.

Answer (score 4):

In the afterword to the [Closed Circle](http://www.closed-circle.net/ebook-catalog/) ebook edition of *Hellburner*, Cherryh states:

> “Dekker, Pollard, Kady, and Aboujib went on to crew the ridership *Freya*, assigned to ECS 5 *Norway.* … *Norway* is distinguished among all the ships in the Fleet for never having lost a rider ship. … [Keu's] *India* had lost two of its riderships, *Ganges* and *Bhramaputra,* by the time it fought at Pell. … Captain Villy, Villanueva, commanded the ridership *Lhasa* aboard the carrier *Tibet* and was lost in the battle of Pell.”

Note that this tally of *India's* riderships lost doesn't fit Bet Yeager's assessment in *Rimrunners*, some years after Pell,  that Thule Station was facing either *Ganges* or *Tigris*; but it's possible Yeager's information was incorrect or out of date, or that she misspoke.